# Kryonet class not registered even though I register

Tags: java, network-programming

I'm making a **2d game** and want to implement **multiplayer**, to be easier I'm ***using an API*** called **[Kryonet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet)**. Following [*this tutorial*](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCBE266DA504BB744). The version of Kryonet I'm using is, like the tutorial, 1.04.

---

I saw all the 6 videos and my code looks a bit like him as you can see:

**Client**:

- [Multiplayer class](http://pastebin.com/A1AVhMSq)
- [NetworkListener class](http://pastebin.com/mHhLi2Ey)
- [Packets classes](http://pastebin.com/844j2jUL)

**Server**:

- [ServerMP class](http://pastebin.com/XL9i6mb0)
- [NetworkListener class](http://pastebin.com/cd88C5wX)
- [Packets classes](http://pastebin.com/844j2jUL)

---

It seems to be fine but then I run the server and the client and **on client I get**:

[image: client console output]

Server runs without an error.

---

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the problem by looking at the [Kryonet Examples](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet/tree/master/examples/com/esotericsoftware/kryonet/examples/chat), it was that on the register method at Multiplayer class it shouldn't be:

```
Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
```

But instead

```
Kryo kryo = client.getKryo();
```